# How to continue a Foreach loop in spite of server connectivity

Tags: sql, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I've built a SSIS package which has a dataflow task within a foreachloop container. The data task has an ole db source and an ole db destination. At the beginning outside of the foreachloop container will be a execute sql task which will provide a list of server names. If my server is not online or cannot connect for any reason, my foreach loop should ignore it and go on to check the next available server. I would also like for this package to populate a specific field in the destination table with a 1 if the connection is found and a 0 if connection isn't found. If the connection isn't found, I would like to send an email alert.

Answer (score 0):

Put an OnError handler on the Execute SQL task.  In it you can update your 1/0 table, and build a string variable for your email body.

Then set the "FailOnError" properties of the Execute SQL task to false so that the package will continue running no matter what.

Comment: The only thing that the Execute SQL task does, is return server names from a stored procedure. The error occurs inside the Data Flow Task, which is when the package searches for server connections

Comment: Sorry I misread that part of the question.   Then you should put the OnError handler on the DataFlow task.

Comment: So what would I use to update the table when the package encounters a failed connection? I would have to provide it another pathway for failed instances right? Just not sure what tools would be required for this

Comment: Depends why the connection fails.   If it's a temporary problem, then just wait and run it again.   If it's permanent then why do you have a bad connection in your list?  Should it be permanently removed from your list of servers?

Comment: The only reason why the connection would fail would be if a server is not connected or cannot be contacted. The point of this package is to send an email notification to a specific person whenever one of the servers are down. And to also keep a record of it in the results table

Comment: Ok, so yes you would use an Execute SQL Task to update your table when a server is down.   That would be in the OnError handler.   If you send one email per server, then you would also do that in the OnError handler.   If you only send one summary email, you would do it at the end of the package, after the loop.

Comment: Okay so in this Execute SQ Task, Is there a way to specify the update in the  results table for the servers with no connection and not any other server. The query I attempted to use updated the server that is used for the local connection...which is active server at the moment

Comment: Of course.  The Execute SQL Task will be inside the loop, so you will be able to use the variable that contains the current connection string to build your update statement.  It is my understanding that you want to update a table on your local server (the same server where you got the list) with a message that the OTHER server you failed to contact is down.   Right?

Comment: Yes. You're understanding is correct. I'm not sure how to go about this. Not sure if we would use the variable in Parameter mapping or use it within the SQL Statement, if that is even a possibility.

Comment: Either approach is possible.   Give it a try and raise a question if you get stuck.

Comment: I appreciate the help a lot! I placed my variable within the Parameter Mapping of the Execute SQL Task, added my query in SQLStatement to populate the table, included a ? within the the query to represent the variable and it worked! Any way to limit the population? For some reason, the server that is down, returns multiple records into the results table instead of just one record per server

Comment: You can limit it with the usual SQL methods, either a WHERE clause, or a GROUP BY, DISTINCT, etc.

Comment: I have a Send Mail task which is included inside the same onError event handler as the Execute SQL Task. Placed it here so that the email alert would be triggered once the package hits an error. Any suggestions on how to limit the sending of email notifications to 1 instead of multiple emails for the same error?

Comment: Yes instead of sending the mail in the OnError, populate a variable with the email body, like I said in my answer.  Then send the email in the PostExecute of the package.